# HTML 5 video controls - click play/pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, controls

Hi to everyone and thank you in advance for the help! I have an html page with only videos (about 20 of them). What i'd like to have is the play/pause click in every one of them (without showing the controls).

Basically when you click in the area of one video, that video should stop and when i click back it should continue playing...
Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: chech out video.js at videojs.com it has that as an option plus much much more i really enjoy using it and it is very simple

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the html5 `video` tag, there are `play()` and `pause()` functions associated with it. You can put a div over the video and toggle the video on its click event. [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPn4J/) with an example of this.

Videos also have a `currentTime` variable that is both readable and writeable, so you can do useful things with that as well.